# Why does Windows constantly ping wireless network bridge?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-xp, wireshark

I was looking at a Wireshark capture off my Windows XP box, and I noticed a rather curious behavior. Every 1-2 seconds, the machine sends a ping request to my Linksys WET610N wireless network bridge, which the Windows box connects to the Internet through.

Why is this happening? And is it possible to disable? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Ping is an ICMP request to test connectivity.  ICMP is necessary for MTU discovery to work correctly. It should be enabled inbound to get top efficiency from your broadband connection.

ICMP MUST not be disabled, for TCP to function properly.  Disabling it makes your network not rfc-compliant and likely to have problems that are hard to troubleshoot.